# Showing that $(A \land B)' \land (C' \land A)' \land (C \land B')' \to A'$ without a truth table

Tags: propositional-calculus

> **Problem:** Prove that $(A \land B)' \land (C' \land A)' \land (C \land B')' \to A'$.

What I have done so far:

1. $(A \land B)'$  *premise*
2. $(C' \land A)'$ *premise*
3. $(C \land B')'$ *premise*
4. $A' \lor B'$ *1, De Morgan*
5. $C \lor A'$ *2, De Morgan*
6. $C' \lor B$ *3, De Morgan*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following: Let
$$
\Omega\equiv\neg(A\land B)\land\neg(\neg C\land A)\land\neg(C\land\neg B)\to\neg A.
$$
Your job, then, is to show that $\Omega$ is a tautology:
\begin{align}
\Omega&\equiv\neg(A\land B)\land\neg(\neg C\land A)\land\neg(C\land\neg B)\to\neg A\tag{by definition}\\[1em]
&\equiv (\neg A\lor\neg B)\land(C\lor\neg A)\land(\neg C\lor B)\to\neg A\tag{DeMorgan}\\[1em]
&\equiv[A\land(B\lor\neg C)]\lor(C\land\neg B)\lor\neg A\tag{mat. imp., distrib.}\\[1em]
&\equiv [(A\lor\neg A)\land(B\lor\neg C\lor\neg A)]\lor(C\land\neg B)\tag{distrib.}\\[1em]
&\equiv (B\lor\neg C\lor\neg A\lor C)\land(B\lor\neg C\lor\neg A\lor\neg B)\tag{distrib.}\\[1em]
&\equiv \mathbf{T}\land\mathbf{T}\\[1em]
&\equiv \mathbf{T}.
\end{align}
The biggest "jump" is from the second to the third step. If you can see that, then you should be well on your way.

Answer (score 3):

$R \equiv(A'\lor B')\land(C\lor A')\land(C'\lor B) $
$\equiv(A'\lor(B'\land C))\land(B\lor C')  $
$\equiv((A'\lor(B'\land C))\land B)\lor ((A'\lor(B'\land C))\land C')$
$\equiv((B\land A')\lor (B\land (B'\land C)) \lor((C'\land A')\lor (C'\land (B'\land C))$
Since $(B\land (B'\land C)) \equiv 0$  and $(C'\land (B'\land C)) \equiv 0$, We have that :
$R \equiv (B\land A')\lor (C'\land A') \equiv A' \land(B\lor C')$
So you can say that if $R\equiv 1$, then $A'\equiv 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Good so far.

You have shown that $(A \land B)' \land (C' \land A)' \land (C \land B')' \equiv (A' \lor B') \land (C \lor A') \land (C' \lor B)$

You can then write $(A' \lor B') \land (C \lor A') \land (C' \lor B) \equiv (A' \lor B') \land \left [(C \lor A') \land C' \lor (C \lor A') \land B) \right]$
 (distributive law)

Then consider smaller parts like $(C \lor A') \land C' \equiv [C \land C'] \lor [A' \land C'] \equiv 0 \lor [A' \land C'] \equiv A' \land C'$

Answer (score 1):

1. (A∧B)′ premise
2. (C′∧A)′ premise
3. (C∧B′)′ premise
4. A′∨B′ 1, De Morgan
5. C∨A′ 2, De Morgan
6. C′∨B 3, De Morgan
7. 'A v B 5, 6 resolution
8. 'A 4, 7 resolution